# c++ testing code

Tags: c++

here is code which print "c++" in binary form and at the same time measure time

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned int t = clock();
    string c = "c++";
    int t=0;
    for (int i=0;i<c.length();i++){
        t = (int) c[i];
        while (t!=0){
            cout << t % 2 <<endl;
            t >>= 1;
        }
    }
    unsigned int end = clock();
    cout << end-t << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but here is mistake

```
1>------ Build started: Project: name_of_c++, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  c++_name.cpp
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\name_of_c++\c++_name.cpp(11): error C2371: 't' : redefinition; different basic types
1>          c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\name_of_c++\c++_name.cpp(7) : see declaration of 't'
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\name_of_c++\c++_name.cpp(12): warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch
1>c:\users\david\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\name_of_c++\c++_name.cpp(16): error C2059: syntax error : '>='
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Don't the error messages say something?

Comment: its a bit pointless asking a question, then editing it so its no longer showing the problem after you've gotten the answers. Leave it as is, or people coming to view your question in future will be very confused.

Comment: so what to do?can i delete it?

Comment: Nothing, you leave it up for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these two lines:

```
unsigned int t=clock();
int t=0;
```

These are both in the same scope, and both define a variable `t`.  This is not allowed in C++!

In case you are having trouble parsing the error message, when you get something like:

```
c++_name.cpp(11): error C2371: 't' : redefinition; different basic types
```

The number in parenthesis (11) tells you the line where the error occurred.

Answer (score 2):

You know, compiler prints line numbers for errors.

Here is a problem:

```
unsigned int t=clock();


string c="c++";
int t=0;
```

First you declare t as unsigned int, and then you declare it as int.

Answer (score 1):

you have declared t as unsigned int first here:

```
unsigned int t=clock();
```

and then defined again here as int

```
 int t=0;
```

You can use a different variable name for the second one to get rid of this error.

Comment: yes i have changed code and it works it was typed error i did not see